# MySQL Connector 6.7.4 Entity Framework 5 Model First

Tags: mysql, entity-framework-5, connector-net

I am using Visual Studion 2012, MySQL 5.6.14, Connector for .NET 6.7.4 and Visual Studio plug-in 1.0.2

I have created an Entity Framework but cannot get "Generate Database from Model" to work.

I have tried the modification suggested here

http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=67964

but now I get the exception below (it appears as though credentials are not getting passed).  Has anyone experienced this?

```
`Error  2   Running transformation: MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): Authentication to host '' for user '' using method 'mysql_native_password' failed with message: Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO) ---> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO)
at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlStream.ReadPacket()
at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Authentication.MySqlAuthenticationPlugin.ReadPacket()
at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Authentication.MySqlAuthenticationPlugin.AuthenticationFailed(Exception ex)
at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Authentication.MySqlAuthenticationPlugin.ReadPacket()
at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Authentication.MySqlAuthenticationPlugin.Authenticate(Boolean reset)
at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.Authenticate(String authMethod, Boolean reset)
at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.Open()
at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.Open()
at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.Create(MySqlConnectionStringBuilder settings)
at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.GetPooledConnection()
at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.TryToGetDriver()
at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.GetConnection()
at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.Open()
at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlScriptServices.GetTableCreateScript(EntitySet entitySet, String connectionString, String version)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplatingD3E432D0E484C972F42C6D13E94510BEB0C48500C7AACE47A3533033751EF00050B7580D6891ADC8583A2327CA5DD242B2AF4C7A11EB05A80839B23CDA63F07B.GeneratedTextTransformation.TransformText() in c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Entity Framework Tools\DBGen\SSDLToMySQL.tt:line 133   c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Entity Framework Tools\DBGen\SSDLToMySQL.tt    133 1`
```

Comment: have you solve your problem!!!
i hace same problem

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need connector 6.8.1 according to release notes.

http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?174,601041,601041#msg-601041

I was able to do it with a lower version connector changing the script generation template from SQL to MySQL that's included on MySQL for visual studio plugin. But may have some issues.